# Ktor: How can I validate JSON request?

Tags: json, kotlin, ktor

I already know how to receive a JSON object and automatically deserialize it into the required format (e.g. with a data class). Also look here: [How to receive JSON object in Ktor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449280/how-to-receive-json-object-in-ktor)

My problem now is that I want to validate the JSON request and return `BadRequest` if it's not in the desired format, something like that in Django: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085405/5005715

How can I do that in Ktor/Kotlin? Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution in the docs. Also, required/optional fields would be nice.

Comment: What's wrong with validating the object after decode? BTW the Django example looks like [JSR-303](https://beanvalidation.org/), but I haven't seen something like this in Ktor

Comment: the problem is that if a mandatory parameter is missing, Jackson will send an Exception because it cannot deserialize the JSON. I have the same issue and I haven't found in the docs how to fail with a BadRequestException

Comment: @Rytek did you find anything which solved your issue?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `hibernate-validator` for input validations. Refer below:

**Add Dependency (Gradle):**

```
compile "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.1.1.Final"
```

**Annotate your data class (DTO):**

```
data class SampleDto(
    @field:Min(value=100)
    val id: Int,
    @field:Max(value=99)
    val age: Int
)
```

**Add Validator in Routing:**

```
import javax.validation.Validation

fun Application.module() {

    val service = SampleService()
    val validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().validator

    routing {
        post("/sample/resource/") {
            val sampleDto = call.receive<SampleDto>()
            sampleDto.validate(validator)
            service.process(sampleDto)
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        }
    }
}

@Throws(BadRequestException::class)
fun <T : Any> T.validate(validator: Validator) {
    validator.validate(this)
        .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
        ?.let { throw BadRequestException(it.first().messageWithFieldName()) }
}

fun <T : Any> ConstraintViolation<T>.messageWithFieldName() = "${this.propertyPath} ${this.message}"
```

**Bonus Step (Optional) - Add Exception Handler:**

```
fun Application.exceptionHandler() {

    install(StatusPages) {
        exception<BadRequestException> { e ->
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorDto(e.message, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.value))
            throw e
        }
    }

}

data class ErrorDto(val message: String, val errorCode: Int)
```

Comment: This is great!!!

I needed additional dependency:
implementation "org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b08"

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick example of how to validate and respond with 400 if needed.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 5000) {
        install(CallLogging)
        install(ContentNegotiation) { gson { } }
        install(Routing) {
            post("test") {
                val sample = call.receive<Sample>()
                if (!sample.validate()) {
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Sample did not pass validation")
                }
                call.respond("Ok")
            }
        }
    }.start()
}

fun Sample.validate(): Boolean = id > 5

data class Sample(val id: Int)
```

Did you have something else in mind?

There are no inbuilt annotations or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the answer of Andreas a step further you can return a list of errors when the request is invalid like so:

```
    post {
        val postDog = call.receive<PostDog>()
        val validationErrors = postDog.validate()
        if (validationErrors.isEmpty()) {

            // Save to database

        } else {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, validationErrors)
        }

    }

    fun PostDog.validate() : List<Error> {
        var validationErrors : MutableList<Error> = mutableListOf()
        if(name == null || name.isBlank())
            validationErrors.add(Error(code = "dog.name.required", message = "Dog requires a name"))
        if(color == null || color.isBlank())
            validationErrors.add(Error(code = "dog.color.required", message = "Dog requires a color"))            
        return validationErrors
    }

    data class PostDog(
      val name: String,
      val color: String          
    )

    data class Error(
        val code : String,
        val message : String
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

use this library

https://github.com/valiktor/valiktor

```
data class Employee(val id: Int, val name: String, val email: String) {
        init {
            validate(this) {
                validate(Employee::id).isPositive()
                validate(Employee::name).hasSize(min = 3, max = 80)
                validate(Employee::email).isNotBlank().isEmail()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure Ktor has already something for that.Spring handles it well with **@Valid annotation**.
I was also looking for something like this to make validation whether of the json or the object. I found this framework https://github.com/making/yavi. It looks interesting. I will make a try